# How can I fix this Syntax error in a for loop in python 3?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
Number = input("Type Your Factor number Here: ")
placeholder = int(Number)
a = 1
placeholder/a = x
for i in range(placeholder+1):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        print(placeholder/a)
    a += 1

SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

it is giving me this error because I can not divide the"placeholder" variable by a.

Comment: any clue about what you try to achieve? these 2 lines are very unclear for me.  placeholder
placeholder/a = x

Comment: I think you'll have to describe what you want because the code before the for loop is confusing and invalid.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the factorial of a number?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a variable "x", which is not defined, to an operation "placeholder/a" which is incorrect.
We assign something to a variable, for example, placeholder = x.

Another thing, you're dividing placeholder by a (a =1) so you can easily remove the division and make: placeholder = x.

PS: Don't forget to define "x".

Answer (score 0):

It works but I don't know what it is doing.

```py
Number = input("Type Your Factor number Here: ")
placeholder = int(Number)
a = 1
x= placeholder/a
print(x,'\n')
for i in range(placeholder+1):
    if isinstance(x, int):
       print(placeholder/a)
    a += 1
```

Just swap x position, you don't need placeholder alone.

Comment: What im trying to achieve is how to divide the value stored in the "placeholder" variable by a which increases each integer in the for a loop. It checks if x is an integer and prints it if it is, it is a factor rainbow thing of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of what the code should do in a recent comment, your code only needs a little reorganisation:

```py
Number = input("Type Your Factor number Here: ")
placeholder = int(Number)
print(placeholder, '\n')
a = 1
for i in range(placeholder+1):
    x = placeholder / a
    if isinstance(x, int):
       print(x)
    a += 1
```

This is what you meant to write, however, I don’t think the code will do what you want it to.

Comment: yeah, it only prints out the value of "placeholder" because I think the insinstance function is not checking if x is an integer or has some error checking over it because if the "placeholder" is equal to 12, what I want it to do is to print 12 6 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 6 12 (it would end up like that just in vertical form). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What you actually need to write is: ‘if placeholder % a == 0: print(placeholder/a) ‘, because in your code ‘x’ will always be a ‘float’, so you can omit ‘x’ altogether.